# Impossible to keep 00:00:00 in a character string in R

Tags: date, lubridate

I would like to have some help on something that is driving me crazy.

I have a date column stored as a character with the format "01-01-2020 12:40:00".

I use this column as an identifier between different dataframe.

Since today and I don't know why, when I import the csv in R using readr the characters containing dates like 01-01-2021 00:00:00 are transformed in 01-01-2021.

I don't get why its taking the liberty to change my character string ???
Because of that I cannot parse the dates correctly...

Thanks a lot.

I tried to convert the csv file in an excell file but the same issue remained.

Comment: Could you share the code you're using to read the data in?